# One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running: error on live server

Tags: magento

[One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running: error on live server. I can't find a way to solve this ..My Magento version is 2.0.16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98eDc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have ssh access :
cd  "your_magento_folder_path" /bin

php magento  setup:cache:clean
php magento  setup:cache:flush
magento setup:static-content:deploy
magento setup:indexer:reindex
magento cron:run

if you have not ssh access 
from the admin panel you go to : System > indexManagement > select all index >and click rindex